# Searching a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of lists called people in python

```
people = [['10000', '2018-02-04', 'Park', 'Chan'], ['10047', '2018-05-09', 'Tuckwell', 'Luke'], ['10207', '2018-05-06', 'Trentham', 'Sam'], ['10207', '2018-05-06', 'Smith', 'Tristin'], ['10511', '2018-02-07', 'Cotton', 'Marco'], ['10763', '2018-03-07', 'Wideman', 'Jocelyn'], ['10804', '2018-05-09', 'Hamm', 'Megan']]
```

Each individual list contains an ID, Expiry Date, Last Name, First Name.

What is the best way to go about defining a function that searches 'people' for a desired ID input and returns whether the expiry date of that person is passed today's date or not? 
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did one of the below solutions help? Feel free to accept one (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you can it is better to convert your list of lists to a dictionary where the key is the ID, this way the searches (when performed by ID) will be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a dictionary to structure your data, mapping id to detail. Another improvement is to store your dates as `datetime` objects.

```
from datetime import datetime

people = [['10000', '2018-02-04', 'Park', 'Chan'], ['10047', '2018-05-09', 'Tuckwell', 'Luke'],
          ['10207', '2018-05-06', 'Trentham', 'Sam'], ['10207', '2018-05-06', 'Smith', 'Tristin'],
          ['10511', '2018-02-07', 'Cotton', 'Marco'], ['10763', '2018-03-07', 'Wideman', 'Jocelyn'],
          ['10804', '2018-05-09', 'Hamm', 'Megan']]

# create a dictionary mapping, convert dates to datetime objects
d = {k: [datetime.strptime(v[0], '%Y-%m-%d'), v[1], v[2]] for k, *v in people}

# function to calculate whether date has passed for given id
def return_date_passed(d, i):
    return d[i][0] < datetime.now()

res = return_date_passed(d, '10000')  # True
res = return_date_passed(d, '10207')  # False
```